# How to change page size to A4 in python-docx

Tags: python, docx, python-docx

I try out creating Word documents with python-docx. The created file is in letter dimensions 8.5 x 11 inches. But in Germany the standard format is A4 8.27 x 11.69 inches.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

document = Document()

document.add_heading('Document Title', 0)
document.settings


p = document.add_paragraph('A plain paragraph having some ')
p.add_run('bold').bold = True
p.add_run(' and some ')
p.add_run('italic.').italic = True

document.add_heading('Heading, level 1', level=1)
document.add_paragraph('Intense quote', style='IntenseQuote')

document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in unordered list', style='ListBullet'
)
document.add_paragraph(
    'first item in ordered list', style='ListNumber'
)



table = document.add_table(rows=1, cols=3)
hdr_cells = table.rows[0].cells
hdr_cells[0].text = 'Qty'
hdr_cells[1].text = 'Id'
hdr_cells[2].text = 'Desc'


document.add_page_break()

document.save('demo.docx')
```

I don't find any information about this topic in the documentation.

Answer (score 16):

```
from docx.shared import Mm

document = Document()
section = document.sections[0]
section.page_height = Mm(297)
section.page_width = Mm(210)
section.left_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.right_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.top_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.bottom_margin = Mm(25.4)
section.header_distance = Mm(12.7)
section.footer_distance = Mm(12.7)
```

Comment: thanks a lot!. I wasted couple of hours trying to find out how to set page margins

Answer (score 8):

It appears that a `Document` is made of several [`Section`](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/section.html#docx.section.Section)s with `page_height` and `page_width` attributes.

To set the dimensions of the first section to A4, you could try (untested):

```
section = document.sections[0]
section.page_height = Mm(297)
section.page_width = Mm(210)
```

Note that A4 is defined in [millimeters](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/shared.html#docx.shared.Mm).

Answer (score 3):

I believe you want this, from the [documentation](http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/sections.html#page-dimensions-and-orientation).

> Three properties on Section describe page dimensions and orientation.
>   Together these can be used, for example, to change the orientation of
>   a section from portrait to landscape:
>
> ```
> >>> section.orientation, section.page_width, section.page_height
> (PORTRAIT (0), 7772400, 10058400)  # (Inches(8.5), Inches(11))
> >>> new_width, new_height = section.page_height, section.page_width
> >>> section.orientation = WD_ORIENT.LANDSCAPE
> >>> section.page_width = new_width
> >>> section.page_height = new_height
> >>> section.orientation, section.page_width, section.page_height
> (LANDSCAPE (1), 10058400, 7772400)
> ```