# Is there an attribute 'fit-to-page' in add_picture() using python docx

Tags: python-docx

I have added a picture in a doc by using python docx. It looks good as long as it's small. But the picture goes next page or it's displayed half of it if the size is too big. How to make my picture 'fit-to-page'.  I dont want to give any constants like Inches-5.5 or something.

```
    p1 = doc.add_paragraph(' ')
    pic = doc.add_picture(os.path.join(base_path, fi),
          width=Inches(5.0))
    para = doc.paragraphs[-1]
```

Comment: You can interrogate the image for its size and reduce large ones, but you cannot detect how close it is to a page boundary and adjust based on that. Also, there is no `fit-to-page` on an inline picture that I know of.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible to get the text width, which is the page width minus the left and right margins, and pass this value to the width argument of add_picture().

An example of a function to get the text width is:

```
def get_text_width(document):
    """
    Returns the text width in mm.
    """
    section = document.sections[0]
    return (section.page_width - section.left_margin - section.right_margin) / 36000
```

You can then call the function when adding a new picture:

```
r.add_picture(image, width=Mm(get_text_width(doc)))
```

If you need to add pictures in different sections of a document, it's necessary to improve the function to address this.

References:

[How to change page size to A4 in python-docx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43724030/how-to-change-page-size-to-a4-in-python-docx)

[https://www.trichview.com/help/units_of_measurement.html#:~:text=English%20metric%20unit%20(EMU)%20is,%2C%201%20mm%20%3D%2036000%20EMU](https://www.trichview.com/help/units_of_measurement.html#:%7E:text=English%20metric%20unit%20(EMU)%20is,%2C%201%20mm%20%3D%2036000%20EMU)